# C# WebClient.UploadData

Tags: c#, webclient, webclient.uploaddata

I'm a .NET newbie and I'm playing with the WebClient class to consume a simple rest service.
What I need to do is post a file to the service with some parameters in QueryString.
The WebClient provides the QueryString NameValueCollection which is designed exactly to pass parameters in a QueryString and it works JUST on Get methods so in my case the QueryString collection doesn't fit because while uploading the file the WebClient is actually doing a POST. So I'm stuck.
Any ideas? thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the query string parameters in the `address` parameter for UploadData:

```
client.UploadData("http://my.server.com/service?id=1&name=foo", myData);
```

Comment: Actually... this works but it turns out that I needed to send the file just like an html form no raw data so I had to use HttpWebRequest.
Anyway thanks!